# How to use scrollToLocation in sectionList to scroll to specific location

Tags: react-native, react-native-sectionlist

I have a `SectionList` as follows,

```
 <SectionList
       ref={ref => this.sectionListRef = ref}
       renderItem={({ item, index, section }) => this.renderItems(item, index, section)}
       renderSectionHeader={({section: {title}}) => this.renderSectionHeader(title)}
       stickySectionHeadersEnabled={false}
       sections={openRequestsArrLength > 0 ? openRequestsArr : []}
       onScroll={(e) => this.handleScroll(e)}
 />
```

and below is the code to take the user to desired list item

```
  this.sectionListRef.scrollToLocation({
       viewOffset: scrollPosition,
       animated: false,
       itemIndex,
       sectionIndex
  });
```

when this code executes getting following error,

> scrollToIndex should be used in conjunction with getItemLayout or
> onScrollToIndexFailed

I am not sure about how to user neither `getItemLayout` nor `onScrollToIndexFailed`.

Can anybody let me know how can i proceed form this point to achieve my requirement that scrolling to desired location?

Thank You.

Edit: `getItemLayout` didn't solve my problem, it just prevent the error that stated above. Any suggestions on how to use `onScrollToIndexFailed` to make `scrollToLocation` works

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React Native getItemLayout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44972206/react-native-getitemlayout)

Comment: @JulesSam.Randolph after implementing this error is not thrown but SectionList is not going to the desired scrollPosition

Comment: @Mighty Any update? Did you find any workaround? I'm facing the same problem. Help would be appreciated.

Comment: @DroidLearnerNot yet...I just kept this aside...Please let m know if you find any answer

Comment: how does one calculate the correct sectionIndex and correct itemIndex to scroll to the correct item?

Comment: It seems you are using `scrollToIndex` instead of `scrollToLocation`. So which one do you want to use?